# How do I backup a database from MySQL 32-bit and restore it to MySQL 64-bit?

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm currently using MySQL version 5.0.16, on my local computer (which runs a 32-bit OS), for easier access while developing my program.

Now that I'm ready to deploy my program, I'd like to test the connection over a network, and use a 64-bit server to hold the database.

Up til now, I've only used the 32-bit version, and my backup 'process' would be to copy the database folder from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data and paste it onto the same directory of another computer.

I'm not sure if that would work.

I tried using both MySQL Query Browser and Command Line Client to do the following:

mysqldump -u root -proot Isys-TMS(EEI1) > isystms.sql;

But both simply return this error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root -proot Isys-TMS(EEI1) > isystms.sql' at line 1"

Which is not at all helpful. (Though I'm not sure if I did it right on the command line client, as opposed to Windows' own CMD)

I'm also assuming I can simply use this .sql output on the new 64-bit MySQL, so if that's not the case, what else can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Notes:

- I'm using Windows 7 32-bit Pro, with MySQL Server 5.0 installed in it.
- I'm planning to move the database to a Windows Server 2008 64-bit, with MySQL Community Server 5.6

EDIT: I actually used mysqldump, not mysqldumb. Quick, someone make a dumb/dump joke.

Comment: Waaaaaait! Are you trying to run `mysqldump` (yes, it's `mysqldump`, by the way, with a **p**, not a **b**) from _inside_ MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did use mysqldump, not mysqldumb. And yes, I used MySQL Query Browser.

Comment: Well, that's wrong, so don't do that.

Comment: I see. So I use Windows Command Line?

Comment: MySQL Query Browser or even HeidiSQL should be able to create a backup... What is the exact error in Query Browser? And by the way - you use Windows - please do not add a semikolon!

Comment: @AndreasRehm, that would be the error I posted above.

Comment: @zack_falcon Please reformat you post - I'm not sure if you run "mysqldump *" or mysqldump without semikolon and qoutes

Comment: And don't get me wrong - this is no SQL code - this is a commandline - you seem to run this in Query Browser or mysql cmd - this is wrong! You can create a backup in Query Browser with the tool itself or by running the mysqldump commandline. See http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql_gui_tools.htm

Comment: Edited. Well, I don't know how to create a backup in Query Browser (1.1.4), but I have since tried to do the command in Windows CMD, as per the answers below.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31174/discussion-between-andreas-rehm-and-zack-falcon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no SQL code:

```
"mysqldump -u root -proot Isys-TMS(EEI1) > isystms.sql;"
```

It is a commandline program like mysql.exe. You seem to run this in Query Browser or mysql cmd - this is wrong!

You can create a backup in Query Browser with the tool itself: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql_gui_tools.htm

or by running the mysqldump commandline from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin` as:

```
mysqldump -u root -proot Isys-TMS(EEI1) -r isystms.sql
```

Please read this too (avoid \n / \r\n conversion): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/mysqldump.html

Restore: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql_gui_tools.htm#restore

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` is a separate binary and not a command within the MySQL console. Furthermore it is spelled with a `p` in the end (you had a `b` there!).

So just use your command on the ordinary command line and it should work.

```
> mysqldump -u root -p "Isys-TMS(EEI1)" > isystms.sql
```

- [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, both the command AND the error message. I tried it on CMD, and it gets me an error 1146: Table 'isys-tms(eei1).toddeven' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES

Comment: @zack_falcon Rest of the answer remains the same: Just execute in the command line (and not the MySQL console).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did. It got me the error I posted on the comment above. I looked said error up on google, and tried mysqlcheck -uroot -proot "isys_tms_eei1" and the check said all the tables were okay.

Answer (score 1):

Properly escape the catalog name and `mysqldump` will work fine from the command line (the **real** command line, not the MySQL command line):

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot "Isys-TMS(EEI1)" > isystms.sql
```

And try to avoid ugly characters like parentheses in your database names in the future. Also prefer `_` over `-`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll keep it in mind, and rename the database. Also, is there any difference between -u root and -uroot?

Comment: Actually for `mysqldump` they're the same.

Answer (score 1):

replace "**mysqldumb** -u root -proot Isys-TMS(EEI1) > isystms.sql;" by "**mysqldump** -u root -proot Isys-TMS(EEI1) > isystms.sql;".

Also, may be you can modify the database name to avoid parantheses

Comment: I'm so sorry, this is what happens when I fail to proof read. It was dump. And it still didn't work. I'll see what renaming the database does. Thanks.

Comment: okk ... here's a suggestion  -->  `lsys_TMS_EEl1`

Comment: Thanks. As per the other answers here, it was a mistake using MySQL query browser to do the command, as opposed to the command line. I'll rename the database and run it from CMD and see what happens.